# How to find and remove string in front of URL?

Tags: 7, hooks, path-aliases, navigation

We have a url pattern of [node:menu-link:parents:join-path]/[node:title].

We are finding that it is resulting in the following urls and we wanted to see if we could use hook_pathauto_alias_alter to remove the undesired string. We are finding that when doing the preg_replace, that is removing all instances where the "/" is found. We just want to remove the string upto the first "/" character. Need assistance in figuring out why it is not working.

```
function mymodule_pathauto_alias_alter(&$alias, array &$context) {
       $patt = '.+(\/)';
       $replacement = '';
       preg_replace($patt, $replace);
}
```

Current results:

- some-text/menu-linka/menu-linkb
- some-text/menu-linka/menu-linkb/menu-linkc

Desired results:

- menu-linka/menu-linkb
- menu-linka/menu-linkb/menu-linkc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see many problems in the code you posted in your question. First of all, you are missing a parameter in `preg_replace`. Take a look at the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

Second, you have no delimiters in your pattern. The correct pattern should be:

`$patt = '/.+\//';`

(You don't need the parenthesis, but you do need delimiters such as slash bars. See [this](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)).

Third, `preg_replace()` returns an array with the replacement. You need to assign the result to $alias, as in `$alias = preg_replace(...)`

I have not use this hook before, but keep in mind (from the description) that this is only invoked before the alias is saved.

Answer (score 0):

you can handle this with [global redirect module](https://www.drupal.org/project/globalredirect), it is useful module that could handle what you want and give your some ability to improve your site SEO.

> GlobalRedirect is a simple module which…
>
> ```
> Checks the current URL for an alias and does a 301 redirect to it if it is not being used.
> Checks the current URL for a trailing slash, removes it if present and repeats check 1 with the new request.
> Checks if the current URL is the same as the site_frontpage and redirects to the frontpage if there is a match.
> Checks if the Clean URLs feature is enabled and then checks the current URL is being accessed using the clean method rather than the
> ```
>
> 'unclean' method.
>       Checks access to the URL. If the user does not have access to the path, then no redirects are done. This helps avoid exposing private
>   aliased node's.
>       Make sure the case of the URL being accessed is the same as the one set by the author/administrator. For example, if you set the alias
>   "articles/cake-making" to node/123, then the user can access the alias
>   with any combination of case.
>       Most of the above options are configurable in the settings page. In Drupal 5 you can access this after enabling the
>   globalredirect_admin module. In Drupal 6, the settings page is bundled
>   into the module.